# Not calling address, but float is returning 0.000-

Tags: c

I have this code here: (Using CLion on a Mac)

```
#include <stdio.h>

float convFtoC(int *, float *);

int main()
{
int min, increment, fahrenheit;
float celsius;

increment = 5;
min = 0;


printf("Please enter a max temperature in Fahrenheit: \n");
scanf("%d", &fahrenheit);

convertFtoC(&fahrenheit, &celsius);

printf("%d degrees Fahrenheit converted is %.4f degrees Celsius \n", fahrenheit, celsius);

printf("%d is the lowest F. The temperatures increment by %d.", min, increment);

return 0;
}

float convFtoC(int *pfahrenheit, float *pcelsius)
{
*pcelsius = (*pfahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9);

return 0;
}
```

My output for celsius becomes 0.00 for all inputs and I can't figure out why. I'm not calling the address of celsius so I'm confused as to why this is happening. Here is example output:

```
Please enter a max temperature in Fahrenheit: 
60
60 degrees Fahrenheit converted is 0.00 degrees Celsius 
0 is the lowest F. The temperatures increment by 5.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `5 / 9` --> `5.0f / 9`

Comment: Wow that works, thanks so much. Is there a way to get it to work that way without tampering with the numbers?

Comment: or `((float)5 / 9);`. The problem was `(5/9)` performs integer division as both its operands are of type `int` and so, it evaluates to zero.

Comment: `5/9 == 0` and anything*0==0.

Comment: There's really no reason to pass the temperature in via an `int *`; you could perfectly well pass an `int`.  Even better would be to use a `float` or `double` for the input value.

Answer (score 4):

You've to force arithmetic to be run in floating point mode.

This can be done by changing `5` to `5.0` or `9`  to `9.0`:

```
*pcelsius = (*pfahrenheit - 32) * (5.0 / 9);
```

Although there's no need for `convFtoC` to return type being `float`; It can be `void`.

Also, You have a typo mistake in calling `convFtoC`